# Unable to search in LDAP database when we have international characters with C#

Tags: c#, active-directory, ldap

I have a web application developed with C#.NET. By using this application, i have to search for users which are in LDAP. I could able to search all the users when i click on search button. But if any user name, has interntaional characters, then i could not get their names when i did search.
Ex: If the name is, Krisård, i can NOT search his name, when i typed Krisård. If i type, kris then i get the name. If I type again Krisård no search results.

Sample code to get the users list.

```
response = (SearchResponse)connection.SendRequest(searcher);
```

Could you please help me.

Comment: What happens if you search for "kris", get the ldap-Path and create an DirectoryEntry object with it? Does it find the user too? And if yes whats the path

Answer (score 0):

Well thats why you should avoid to create users in AD with special or international characters.

You might try to convert it to utf8.

```
String name = "Krisård";
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(name);
name = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
//Now search with variable "name"
```

Also see [Characters to Escape](http://www.rlmueller.net/CharactersEscaped.htm)